# indesign bleed after export not showing color past bleed line

Tags: adobe-indesign, bleed

I'm exporting a finished magazine. After doing the layout, I added in bleed of 0.125 in on all sides. Then I manually expanded the blocks of color I wanted to expand to the bleed. I checked to make sure they lined up. [image]

I then exported the document with the Press Quality preset and all of printer's marks with  a 0.0833 in offset and document bleed settings. I ended up with something that looks like this: [image] where it looks like the block of color doesn't go past the bleed. Any idea what happened?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like the blue colour is part of a rectangle nested inside. You will have to add the same colour blue to the rectangle or set the position to fill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really only one of two things..

- 1. The art isn't actually extended into the bleed area (exit Preview mode and check) -- For example, if that's a *placed image*, merely increasing the image frame doesn't mean there's actual artwork in the bleed area of the frame. You really shouldn't adjust artwork for bleeds in Preview Mode. You can't see anything. There's no way to know if art merely stops at the trim or not.

or...

- 2. The "use document bleeds" wasn't ticked when exported to PDF. Telling the export to merely include bleed marks *doesn't* tell the export to include the document bleed.

---

**My guess would be #1**... there's not actually *any* art in the bleed area. You've merely increased the frame size and art stops at the trim. I can't be certain because your animation shows Preview Mode.

Comment: Ah ha! I never considered the placed image problem! Thank you for your ridiculously quick and helpful response!